# coc not working in latest vim

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-coc

I've installed coc following the instruction, using Vim-Plug (before that I did it without installing yarn and with kite still (partially) installed. I got a 'javascript file not found' error So I uninstalled and reinstalled, then I got this:

[image]

This time no errors, but the thing just isn't working. I tried :call coc#util#install(), does not help.

Is there any other step I should take in order to make this work? If not, how can I debug this business to understand what's the problem?

EDIT: I further ran :CocInstall coc-python, it asked me to install a linter, I chose install. The installation went on, there were several errors that popped up, but it was to fast in order to read them.

EDIT 2: when running :CocConfig I get this:

[image]

EDIT 3: tried to install from branch, also, nothing.

EDIT 4: seems that it does autocomplete perhaps only the commands I already used in the current document. See screenshot:

[image]

EDIT 5: some details that might be relevant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My .vimrc:

```
set ruler
set ai
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set showcmd
set clipboard+=unnamed
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
set belloff+=ctrlg  " if vim beeps during completion
set completeopt+=preview
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{kite#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
set laststatus=2

nnoremap <plug>(slash-after) zz

let g:lightline = {
      \ 'colorscheme': 'one',
      \ }
let g:vim_search_pulse_mode = 'cursor_line'
let g:python_highlight_all = 1
let g:codi#width = 60
let g:kite_auto_complete=1
let g:kite_tab_complete=1

nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w <bar> :exec '!clear && python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>

"Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux.
"If you're using tmux version 2.2 or later, you can remove the outermost $TMUX check and use tmux's 24-bit color support
"(see < http://sunaku.github.io/tmux-24bit-color.html#usage > for more information.)
if (empty($TMUX))
  if (has("nvim"))
    let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
  endif
  if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif
endif

colorscheme onedark


if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Make sure you use single quotes

Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'lfv89/vim-interestingwords'
Plug 'junegunn/vim-slash'
Plug 'inside/vim-search-pulse'
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plug 'tmsvg/pear-tree'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plug 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
let g:pymode_python = 'python3'

let g:indentLine_color_term = 239
let g:indentLine_char_list = ['|', '¦', '┆', '┊']
let g:indentLine_conceallevel=1
```

My .zshrc:

```
bindkey "^[^[[D" backward-word
bindkey "^[^[[C" forward-word

# Aliases
alias ls='colorls'
alias lc='colorls -lA --sd'
alias vim="/usr/local/bin/vim"
alias _z='vim ~/.zshrc'
alias _v='vim ~/.vimrc'

source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh

# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block, everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi


# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/idankor/.oh-my-zsh"
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions colored-man-pages)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
source /Users/idankor/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

# ----------------------------------
# Colors
# ----------------------------------
NOCOLOR='\033[0m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
ORANGE='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHTGRAY='\033[0;37m'
DARKGRAY='\033[1;30m'
LIGHTRED='\033[1;31m'
LIGHTGREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
LIGHTBLUE='\033[1;34m'
LIGHTPURPLE='\033[1;35m'
LIGHTCYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'

function _help() {
echo " "
echo -e ${RED}tldr
echo " "
echo -e ${ORANGE}bro
echo " "
echo -e ${GREEN}eg
echo " "
echo -e ${BLUE}cheat
echo " "
echo -e ${YELLOW}cht.sh
echo " "
}

function cht.sh() {
    curl cht.sh/$1
}
```

Comment: Please please please dont post screenshots of text. Check `:messages` for the installation error. You might have more luck asking their github issue tracker.

Comment: Try :Cocinfo and :Coclist, extensions to verify cocpython is installed and up.

Comment: I don't see coc in your vim plug